# How many schemas can I create in a single Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, database-design

Does Oracle Standard Edition have any limits to creating multiple schemas?

Comment: What part of the product description/documentation did you try to find an answer to that in? Do you want to know this for a particular product version? How does this pertain to programming? [Database administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) may be able to (correctly) answer this while sound asleep.

Comment: @greybeard - database schemas are a vital component of data modelling and database application design. As such I think this is a valid programming question. Unless of course you don't agree database development is programming, but it's considered such on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A schema is a collection of objects owned by a user account. We can have as many users as we like.

The nearest thing to a limit is scalability, and but that governs the number of *concurrent* connections not the total of users. Obviously Standard Edition is constrained here, because it's limited to servers with no more than four cores.